# Class "League\Uri\Modifier" is missing from package?

Tags: symfony6

On my Symfony6 project I wish to use this package:
https://packagist.org/packages/league/uri

[The documentation](https://uri.thephpleague.com/) suggests this usage, that would fit my use-case:

```php
$newUri = Modifier::from($uri)->appendQuery('q=new.Value');
echo $newUri; // 'http://example.com?q=value&q=new.Value#fragment'
```

Yet the `Modifier` class is absent from the package. It was added via: `composer require league/uri` and is at version 7.3.0.
I guess the doc is not up to date, but how do I modify URIs with the lastest version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component is divided into different repositories. To use Modifiers, One needs to install:
`composer require league/uri-components`

Also, there is more doc here:
https://uri.thephpleague.com/components/7.0/modifiers/